# How do I bind a ::std::vector of arguments to a functor?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'm trying to make this program compile properly:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int f(int a, int b)
{
   ::std::cout << "f(" << a << ", " << b << ") == " << (a + b) << '\n';
   return a + b;
}

template <typename R, typename V>
R bind_vec(R (*f)(), const V &vec, int idx=0)
{
   return f();
}

template <typename R, typename V, typename Arg1, typename... ArgT>
R bind_vec(R (*f)(Arg1, ArgT...), const V &vec, int idx=0)
{
   const Arg1 &arg = vec[idx];
   auto call = [arg, f](ArgT... args) -> R {
      return (*f)(arg, args...);
   };
   return bind_vec(call, vec, idx+1);
}

int foo()
{
   ::std::vector<int> x = {1, 2};
   return bind_vec(f, x);
}
```

Ideally I'd like `bind_vec` to take an arbitrary functor as an argument instead of just a function pointer. The idea is to pull the function arguments from a `::std::vector` at compile time.

This isn't the final use for this, but it's a stepping stone to where I want to go. What I'm really doing is generating wrapper functions that unwrap their arguments from promises in a future/promise type system at compile time. These wrapper functions will themselves be promises.

In my ultimate use-case I can count on the functors being `::std::function`s. But it would be nice to have an idea of how it should work for more general functors as well since I think this is a broadly interesting problem.

Comment: Can we simplify this: Do you want a gadget that calls a function of *n* arguments given an arbitrary container by calling the function with the first *n* elements of the container?

Comment: @KerrekSB: Yes. But it has to be a container that is populated with elements at runtime. And preferably it would call anything that implemented `operator ()`.

Comment: @Xeo: Oh, I suppose it doesn't _really_ involve currying in the normal sense. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, first off, detecting the arity of a functor can be done, but it's a bit involved and best left to a separate question. Let's assume you will specify the arity of the functor in the call. Similarly, there are ways to obtain the return type of a callable object, but that's also beyond the scope of this question. Let's just assume the return type is `void` for now.

So we want to say,

```
call(F f, C v);
```

and that should say `f(v[0], v[1], ..., v[n-1])`, where `f` has arity `n`.

Here's an approach:

```
template <unsigned int N, typename Functor, typename Container>
void call(Functor const & f, Container const & c)
{
    call_helper<N == 0, Functor, Container, N>::engage(f, c);
}
```

We need the helper:

```
#include <functional>
#include <cassert>

template <bool Done, typename Functor, typename Container,
          unsigned int N, unsigned int ...I>
struct call_helper
{
    static void engage(Functor const & f, Container const & c)
    {
        call_helper<sizeof...(I) + 1 == N, Functor, Container,
                    N, I..., sizeof...(I)>::engage(f, c);
    }
};

template <typename Functor, typename Container,
          unsigned int N, unsigned int ...I>
struct call_helper<true, Functor, Container, N, I...>
{
    static void engage(Functor const & f, Container const & c)
    {
        assert(c.size() >= N);
        f(c[I]...);
    }
};
```

**Example:**

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

void f(int a, int b) { std::cout << "You said: " << a << ", " << b << "\n"; }

struct Func
{
    void operator()(int a, int b) const
    { std::cout << "Functor: " << a << "::" << b << "\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v { 20, 30 };
    call<2>(f, v);
    call<2>(Func(), v);
}
```

**Notes:** In a more advanced version, I would deduce the arity of the callable object with some more template machinery, and I would also deduce the return type. For this to work, you'll need several specializations for free functions and various CV-qualified class member functions, though, and so this would be getting too large for this question.

Comment: This obviously works for functors. It's not immediately clear how to extend the other one for functors without the arity computation you mention.

Comment: The approach I ended up using is closest to this. But @Xeo's answer was also very good.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this is easily possible for (member) function pointers, but for functors with potentially overloaded `operator()`, this gets a dang lot harder. If we assume that you have a way to tell how many arguments a function takes (and assume that the container actually has that many elements), you can just use the [indices trick](http://loungecpp.wikidot.com/tips-and-tricks%3aindices) to expand the vector into an argument list, for example with `std::next` and a `begin()` iterator:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iterator>

template<class F, class Args, unsigned... Is>
auto invoke(F&& f, Args& cont, seq<Is...>)
  -> decltype(std::forward<F>(f)(*std::next(cont.begin(), Is)...))
{
  return std::forward<F>(f)(*std::next(cont.begin(), Is)...);
}

template<unsigned ArgC, class F, class Args>
auto invoke(F&& f, Args& cont)
  -> decltype(invoke(std::forward<F>(f), cont, gen_seq<ArgC>{}))
{
  return invoke(std::forward<F>(f), cont, gen_seq<ArgC>{});
}
```

This implementation works really nice for random-access containers, but not so well for forward and especially input ones. To make those work in a performant fashion, you might try to go the route of incrementing the iterator with every expanded step, but you'll run into a problem: Evaluation order of arguments to a function is unspecified, so you'll very likely pass the arguments in the wrong order.

Luckily, there is a way to force evaluation left-to-right: The list-initialization syntax. Now we just need a context where that can be used to pass arguments, and a possible one would be to construct an object, pass the function and the arguments through the constructor, and call the function in there. However, you lose the ability to retrieve the returned value, since constructors can't return a value.

Something I thought of is to create an array of *iterators*, which point to the correct element, and expanding those again in a second step where they are dereferenced.

```
#include <utility>

template<class T> using Alias = T; // for temporary arrays

template<class F, class It, unsigned N, unsigned... Is>
auto invoke_2(F&& f, It (&&args)[N], seq<Is...>)
  -> decltype(std::forward<F>(f)(*args[Is]...))
{
  return std::forward<F>(f)(*args[Is]...);
}

template<class F, class Args, unsigned... Is>
auto invoke_1(F&& f, Args& cont, seq<Is...> s)
  -> decltype(invoke_2(std::forward<F>(f), std::declval<decltype(cont.begin())[sizeof...(Is)]>(), s))
{
  auto it = cont.begin();
  return invoke_2(std::forward<F>(f), Alias<decltype(it)[]>{(void(Is), ++it)...}, s);
}

template<unsigned ArgC, class F, class Args>
auto invoke(F&& f, Args& cont)
  -> decltype(invoke_1(std::forward<F>(f), cont, gen_seq<ArgC>{}))
{
  return invoke_1(std::forward<F>(f), cont, gen_seq<ArgC>{});
}
```

The code was tested against GCC 4.7.2 and works as advertised.

---

Since you said that the functors you are getting passed are `std::function`s, getting the number of arguments they take is really easy:

```
template<class F> struct function_arity;

// if you have the 'Signature' of a 'std::function' handy
template<class R, class... Args>
struct function_arity<R(Args...)>
  : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, sizeof...(Args)>{};

// if you only have the 'std::function' available
template<class R, class... Args>
struct function_arity<std::function<R(Args...)>>
  : function_arity<R(Args...)>{};
```

Note that you don't even need `function_arity` to make `invoke` from above work for `std::function`:

```
template<class R, class... Ts, class Args>
R invoke(std::function<R(Ts...)> const& f, Args& cont){
  return invoke_1(f, cont, gen_seq<sizeof...(Ts)>{})
}
```

Comment: I would +1 this, aside from the fact that I don't think I can wrap my head around how it works. :-)

Comment: @Omnifarious: Where exactly are the problems? For the indices trick, I linked the lounge wiki, and there are a good number of answers on SO using it. For everything else, just ask and I'll try to explain (better).

Comment: @Xeo: I think what I'm missing is understanding the indices trick. I'll read up on the link you posted.

Comment: What's the definition of `gen_seq`? Oh! I see. It generates the indices. Hmmm... And ArgC, does that have to be supplied by hand?

Comment: @Omnifarious: As I said, I assumed in this post that you have *some* way to aquire the actual argument count the function (object) shall be invoked with. For `std::function`, it's rather easy to get. Added the code.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do what you want. It's simplest to explain if I leave it as not deducing the correct return type at first, I'll show how to add that later on:

```
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

namespace {
  int f(int a, int b) { return 0; }
}

template <typename ...Args>
constexpr unsigned nb_args(int (*)(Args...)) {
  return sizeof...(Args);
}

template <typename F, typename V, typename ...Args>
auto bind_vec(F f, const V&, Args&& ...args)
 -> typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Args) == nb_args(F()),void>::type
{
  f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template <typename F, typename V, typename ...Args>
auto bind_vec(F f, const V& v, Args&& ...args)
 -> typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Args) < nb_args(F()),void>::type
{
  bind_vec(f, v, std::forward<Args>(args)..., v.at(sizeof...(Args)));
}

int main() {
  bind_vec(&f, std::vector<int>(), 1);
  return 0;
}
```

There are two versions of this `bind_vec` - one is enabled if the parameter pack is the right size for the function. The other is enabled if it is still too small. The first version simply dispatches the call using the parameter pack, whilst the second version gets the next element (as determined by the size of the parameter pack) and recurses.

There SFINAE is done on the return type of the function in order that it not interfer with the deduction of the types, but this means it needs to be done after the function since it needs to know about `F`. There's a helper function that finds the number of arguments needed to call a function pointer.

To deduce the return types also we can use `decltype` with the function pointer:

```
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

namespace {
  int f(int a, int b) { return 0; }
}

template <typename ...Args>
constexpr unsigned nb_args(int (*)(Args...)) {
  return sizeof...(Args);
}

template <typename F, typename V, typename ...Args>
auto bind_vec(F f, const V&, Args&& ...args)
 -> typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Args) == nb_args(F()),decltype(f(std::forward<Args>(args)...))>::type
{
  return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template <typename F, typename V, typename ...Args>
auto bind_vec(F f, const V& v, Args&& ...args)
 -> typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Args) < nb_args(F()),decltype(bind_vec(f, v, std::forward<Args>(args)..., v.at(sizeof...(Args))))>::type
{
  return bind_vec(f, v, std::forward<Args>(args)..., v.at(sizeof...(Args)));
}

int main() {
  bind_vec(&f, std::vector<int>(), 1);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Will this work for functor objects with an `operator()` as well?

Comment: @KerrekSB - with an appropriate overload for `nb_args()` it would.

Comment: @Flexo: Good luck creating one - `operator()` can be overloaded. With a function pointer, the user already has to disambiguate which one he means before passing it to your function.

Comment: @Flexo: In the particular case I'm really worried about down the road, I can count on the functor being a `::std::function`.

Comment: @Xeo - yeah I'm not quite sure how that would work in general although in this instance the type is effectively fixed by the value_type of the vector so you could SFINAE brute-force it to find the first one that works.

Comment: @Omnifarious: That makes it easy, why didn't you say so in the question?

Comment: @Xeo: I was hoping to have the answers be as broadly relevant as possible, since I think this is an interesting problem in the general case and not just my specific case.

Comment: @Flexo: Right, that's the only sensible solution for the overloaded case. You have a `decltype(f(args...))` SFINAE check on every call, and if it fails, you add another argument to the pack. I'm currently editing my answer to explore in that direction.

Comment: @Xeo: Is there an easy way to get some sort of pack of argument types out of a `::std::function`?