# Passing vector items to function-object with unknown number of parameters

Tags: c++, c++11

Here is a simplified version of what I am trying to achieve:

```
template <class Func, class Params>
void foo(Func f, Params p) {
  f(p[0], p[1], ...) // <-- this is the problem. How to do this?
}
...
foo([](int a, int b){ cout<<(a+b); }, std::vector<int>{1,2});
foo([](char a){ cout<<a; }, std::vector<char>{'a'});
```

I hope the problem is clear.

**EDIT:**

The above example did not convey the problem well. I have a vector, populated at some earlier stage, of the parameters. I want a function that will accept a function-object and call it with the parameters from the vector. I can assume that the vector size is equal to the number of parameters.

Hopefully better example:

```
class C {
  std::vector<int> v;
public:
  void add_param(int);
  ... // other functions that manipulate the vector in various ways

  template<class Func>
  void run(Func f) {
    f(v[0], etc...); // <-- problem
  }
};
```

Comment: Have you really need `vector` ? `foo([](int a, int b){ cout<<(a+b); }, 1,2);` would be simpler.

Comment: Else you can retrieve the arity of the functor thanks to a function_traits (so cannot handle several overload `operator ()`), and use an helper function and use `std::index_sequence` as index.

Comment: After your edit, your question is an exact copy of the following. Please look there, the answers are very detailed:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594721/how-do-i-bind-a-stdvector-of-arguments-to-a-functor

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I bind a ::std::vector of arguments to a functor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594721/how-do-i-bind-a-stdvector-of-arguments-to-a-functor)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use something like:

```
// Minimal traits to have information about function
template <typename Func> struct function_traits;

template <typename Ret, typename ... Ts>
struct function_traits<Ret (Ts...)>
{
    constexpr static auto arity = sizeof...(Ts);
};

template <typename Ret, typename ... Ts>
struct function_traits<Ret (*)(Ts...)> : function_traits<Ret(Ts...)> {};

template <typename C, typename Ret, typename ... Ts>
struct function_traits<Ret (C::*)(Ts...) const> : function_traits<Ret(Ts...)> {};

template <typename C>
struct function_traits : function_traits<decltype(&C::operator())> {};

namespace detail
{

    template <typename F, typename Vec, std::size_t ... Is>
    void call(const F& f, Vec&& v, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        f(v[Is]...);
    }
}


template <class Func, class Vec>
void foo(const Func& f, Vec&& v) {
    detail::call(f,
                 std::forward<Vec>(v),
                 std::make_index_sequence<function_traits<Func>::arity>());
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/rBfw9m)

Comment: Very nice solution.

Comment: Wow. It actually worked great, but I am going to have to spend at least an hour breaking that down to figure out what you did there...
Thanks

Comment: @baruch: `function_traits` is there to get the arity of the functor (number of arguments). From that, I construct a compile time sequence `<std::size_t, 0, 1, 2, ..., N>` to allow variadic pack.

Answer (score 6):

You can use variardic templates:

```
template <class Func, class... Params>
void foo(Func f, Params... p) {
  f(p...);
}

foo([](int a, int b){ cout<<(a+b); }, 1, 2);
foo([](char a){ cout<<a; }, 'a');
```

Comment: Thank you. Maybe my example wasn't good. I will try to clarify it. I am not actually getting the parameters in the template. I have a vector that I need to pass the items of to a function object that I get as the template

Comment: That is not as easy, as you might expect. But it can be done. Have a look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594721/how-do-i-bind-a-stdvector-of-arguments-to-a-functor

Comment: @baruch The problem with using vectors is that its size can not usually be calculated at compile-time (when templates are resolved). That is you must know the size of the vector at compile-time. If you populate the vector at run-time there's simply no way to use a vector.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You can work around this issues, with either assuming, the vector has the same size as the arity of the function or using std::array instead. However both ways are not very nice to implement and most likely hint a broken design.